# How to get a utf code from symbol in linux

Tags: shell, utf-8, hexdump

I'm struggling with a special symbol in a text file on linux. I actually successfully pasted it between the following letters "a‏a" (my cursor in Geany stops but no character is displayed).

I'd like to know what's the easiest way to get its utf8 code (in the form U+0000). I'm using ubuntu and geany and I tried hexdump on a file containing it but I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: Don't confuse Unicode code points and their UTF-8 representation. For example, U+0410 is a capitol Cyrillic A, but its UTF-8 representation is 0xD0 0x90.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering how to use unicode codes in grep regular expressions and it turned out I needed the UTF-8 representation byte by byte (since my files use utf-8 I guess). Anyway, bites were: 0xE2 0x80 0x8F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could open the file with vim, put the text cursor over the character, then type 'ga' (without quotes) and it will display the character code in decimal, hex and octal in the status line.

Comment: Thank you, it was right-to-left, vim actually displayed it right away: a<200f>a.